# using custom templates rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, saas, subdomain

I am setting up a SAAS solution where as each account has its own subdomain e.g. sub1.mydomain.com sub2.mydomain.com and in the application template I have setup a standard 2 column template in which I want to include on the aside column a custom partial for each site, as well as a custom style.css file for each subdomain. 
So I'm wondering how could I set this up to show that custom info. I would like to setup a style controller - so it only shows the items of the left sidebar, and the style.css page for each domain name its associated with does anyone have any good ideas?

Basically for a static pages controller I have that setup already, as well as another DB action 
But any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the project I'm working on: https://github.com/fabiob/guildhost-hosting

The code you need is in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :load_subdomain

  def load_subdomain
    @subdomain = self.request.subdomains[0] || 'local'
    load_customer

    raise "Invalid Subdomain: #{self.request.subdomains}" unless @subdomain.present?
  end

  def load_customer
    @customer = Customer.find(@subdomain)
  end
end
```

Also in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= @customer.name %> @ MySaaS.com.br</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "/themes/#{@subdomain}/main.css" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

There's a `/public/themes` folder in which resides the customization for each subdomain. Each subdomain has the opportunity to customize a single CSS, `main.css`. If more than one CSS file is needed, `@import` clauses should be used on `main.css`.

Comment: Thanks since we now have the before filter tag, can I pull out of each action somehow to find a global id?   @accountid = Account.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomain).id